# Android new Intent not responding after ListView

Tags: android, android-intent

I wanted to devise some intents between two activities. I passed the intent without declaring anything . I wanted to define Adapter to inflate listview in the intent but I came across the issue when the intent is opened . It is caused by listview. How can I solve it out?

Here are the code below.

```
public class AttactivePlacesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<City> c = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a);

        MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
        c = m.mArraylist;


        AAdapter r = new AAdapter(this,c,R.color.mainBackground);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.aa);

        listView.setAdapter(r);




    }
}
```

R.layout.a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/aa"
    tools:context="com.example.android.tourguide.AttactivePlacesActivity">

</ListView>
```

gridview Intent

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            switch (position){

                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AttactivePlacesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't see any Intent in the code that you posted. Anyway, your question is unclear

Comment: Please rewrite the question to actually state the problem, reproduction path and desired outcome.

Comment: There is an issue from listView.setAdapter(r); . That means to cause from AAdapter.

Comment: @DRF if the issue is about the .setAdapter, why you talk about Intents?

Comment: Because, The intent is not opened related with Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You create a reference of `MainActivity` to get the `mArrayList`, don't you? Firstly, pls don't create any reference of an activity in another one. Secondly, if you want to get the `mArraylist` in the second activity, just put it in intent like this:

> intent.putSerializable("My array",mArrayList);

and receive it by using:

> c = getIntent.getSerializable("My array");

P/S: Some advices for you, please name the variable by the meaningful name, try to learn the OOP java carrefully before starting with Android. And the last one, searching before asking